# excel - find ramdomly located value and return value in cell to the left

Tags: excel

I need to find multiple randomly located instances of a value "windows_group" on a worksheet named "data" and return the value of the cell to the left of the "windows_group" cells to another worksheet "Windows_Groups".

The worksheet "data" only has data in columns A-G, but can have up to 5000 rows.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." Asking for people to do your homework that you haven't even started is a no-no at Stackoverflow. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

there might be a more graceful to do this, but a brute force way would be a macro that loops through your cells and uses the offset method:

```
sub FindAndReturn() 'I'm not good at naming
dim cell as range
dim i as integer
dim k as integer
k = 1

for each cell in Worksheets("Data").Range("B1:G5000") ' i'm assuming this has to start in column B if you want the value to the left
     if cell.value = "windows_group" Then
          Worksheets("Windows_Groups").Range("A" & k).Value = cell.offset(0,-1).value
          k=k+1
     End if
next cell
end sub
```

Comment: ----   I saved that macro in the spreadsheet and saved as .xlsm file - but when I run it - nothing appears on the Windows_Groups worksheet.

Comment: Are all the strings (text to look for, sheet names, etc.) exactly as they should be/appear in your workbook?

Comment: Check you make sure all the strings are correct, including capitalization.

Comment: Holy caps batman!  I didn't have the all caps in my "WINDOWS_GROUP" value ---  now it works great!   Thank you so very much!  @bbadgett